# save is not working for join table column

Tags: hibernate

hi i m unable to understand why this is  happening i m saving a new entity it saves all the columns but not join table column and none of exceptions thrown code given below for saving a new entity..

```
newEntity=setPropsFromTransientFields(newEntity,"newEntity");
sess.save(newEntity);
```

but when i tried to update a exixting record then it saves succesfullly the join table column

```
persistedEntity=setPropsFromTransientFields(persistedEntity,"updateEntity");
sess.saveOrUpdate(persistedEntity);
```

join table mapping given below

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=TechnologyProduct.class)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "contact_technology",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="technology_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    public List<TechnologyProduct> getTechKeywords() {
        return techKeywords;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate by default does not trying to do any cascade operation. So if you have entity

```
class E{
   List<X> xes;
}
```

then you are responsible for proper handling of the relation `xes`. That is you need to make sure that X entities are saved in DB. You can also configure cascade save, then Hibernate will take care about this by itself.

Your update works as you expect because related objects (X in my example) were added to Hibernate Session before and Hibernate automatically tracks their changes and does all necessary DB operations. That's my guess, since I can't see how to object is read from DB.